# Has this weaker form of the abc conjecture been proven?

Tags: number-theory

Is it known whether or not there exists a (fixed) $r > 0$ such that the following holds:

For all $\epsilon>0$ only finitely many coprime triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b=c$ satisfy

$$\text{rad}(abc)^{1 + r + \epsilon} <c$$

If so what's the smallest known $r$?